# Linearly Dependent Sets and Linear Combinations (Proof Verification)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm practicing my proof-writing and was hoping you could let me know if this proof looks good. I would like to know if the proof is incorrect, if there are parts that are overly wordy/complicated, or if I'm missing some element of a proof that is helpful to see, if not strictly necessary.

**The Prompt (from [here](https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/ARE211/currentYear/problem_sets/psLinAlgebra1Qu.pdf)):**

for n > 1, (v<sub>1</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub>) is a linear dependent set if and only if one of the vector in the set v<sub>i</sub> is a linear combination of the other n − 1 vectors.

**My Proof:**

Suppose (v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>n</sub>) is a linearly dependent set. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> = 0 for some nonzero **t** ∈ R<sup>n</sup>. Let v<sub>k</sub> be a vector s.t. t<sub>k</sub> != 0. Then:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> = 0

$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + t<sub>k</sub>v<sub>k</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> = 0

t<sub>k</sub>v<sub>k</sub> = -$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> - $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ 
t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>

v<sub>k</sub> = -($\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>) / t<sub>k</sub>

Thus v<sub>k</sub> can be written as a linear combination of the other n-1 vectors (since t<sub>k</sub> != 0).

Now suppose one of the vectors in the set v<sub>i</sub>, denoted v<sub>k</sub>, is a linear combination of the other n-1 vectors, so:

v<sub>k</sub> = $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>

for some **s** ∈ R<sup>n</sup>, where s<sub>k</sub> = 0. Then if we define **t** ∈ R<sup>n</sup> s.t. t<sub>i</sub> = s<sub>i</sub> for all values except t<sub>k</sub>, which equals -1, then:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> =

$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + (-1)v<sub>k</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> =

$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> - ($\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> + $\sum_{i=k+1}^n$ s<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub>) = 0

So $\sum_{i=1}^n$ t<sub>i</sub>v<sub>i</sub> = 0 when t != 0, so the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: It looks fine to me.